# using socket.io in express routes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, routes

I want to implement socket on one of my routes. I have a file named

**index.js**

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var http=require("http").Server(app);
var io=require("socket.io")(http);

// one of my route 'polling'

var polling=require('./polling_server.js');
app.use('/',polling);

// lots of code here

http.listen(3000);
```

Now i have another file named **polling_server.js** in which i want to implement socket.

```
module.exports=(function(){
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get("/polling",function()
{
 console.log("Hello from polling");
});

 // I want to access io object in this file

io.on("connection",function(socket){

 });
}) ();
```

In above route **polling_server.js** i want to access io object. When i run this code it shows me

```
io is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define io at the top of polling_server.js, like this:

```
var socket = io();
```

Then use socket like this:

```
socket.on("connection",function(socket){
```

Comment: Sorry the code you have suggested works on client side. But i am asking about server side. Please can you elaborate your answer? I will accept your answer.